# Writing rdbms data to s3 bucket using flink or pyflink

Tags: apache-flink, flink-sql, pyflink, flink-batch

If this kind of error occur while writing data to s3 bucket using flink and pyflink:

ERROR] Could not execute SQL statement. Reason:
org.apache.flink.util.SerializedThrowable: The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records. (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: InvalidAccessKeyId; Request ID: 0VWJS6CJ284XSSKQ; S3 Extended Request ID: bDPWgLBYyMicU+OFBWb1ZX3c1jN58LQRYu5H3zFaszag/swPAGy9V3GZEF14UFJ1QwLj9TN+T9w=; Proxy: null)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Answer: You make sure that your aws account and s3 bucket are present in the same region. Because after making this change my issue has been resolved. I hope this can help you.